# Не отрабатывается скрипт на хостинге

Tags: php, laravel

Не отрабатывается скрипт отправки писем на хосте. На локальной машине в OpenServer работает всё отлично, а на хосте нет, письма не уходят. И если отправляется форма с перезагрузкой, то всё работает, а форма с ajax нет, хотя функции идентичны. В php.ini запретов в disabled_function нет.

```html
 $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
           'name' => 'required',
           'phone' => 'required',
           'date' => '',
           'captcha' => 'required',
           'captcha_two' => '',
       ]);

       if ($validator->passes() & $request->get('captcha') == $request->get('captcha_two')) {

           $newChallenge = new AppFeedback();

           $newChallenge->name    = $request->get('name');
           $newChallenge->phone   = $request->get('phone');
           $newChallenge->date   = $request->get('date');

           $newChallenge->save();
           
           //Здесь начинается отправка писем.

           $details = [
               'title' => 'Заявка на обратный звонок',
               'body' => 'Перезвоните клиенту!',
               'name' => 'Имя: '.$request->get('name'),
               'phone' => 'Номер: '.$request->get('phone'),
               'email' => '',
               'address' => '',
               'price' => '',
               'project' => '',
           ];

           $mails = DB::table('users')->get('email');

           foreach ($mails as $email) {
             \Mail::to($email)->send(new SendMail($details));
           }

           return response()->json(['success'=>'Отправлено!']);


       }

       return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
```

Comment: 1. смотрите логи на сервере. 2. включите удалённую отладку и произведите дебаг. 3. на худой конец включите отображение ошибок на сервере (куда деваться) и посмотрите. .4. совсем на худой - принт_р на серваке построчно

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский в логах ничего, дебагом пользоваться не умею, ошибок никаких не выводится.

Comment: ошибки в консоли какие? в network вкладке и в целом в console? тут других вариантов нет, если что-то не работает - ошибки обязательно есть. error_reporting(E_ALL)  стоит?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский в консоли ничего и сети тоже.  error_reporting(E_ALL) - я не знаю что это

Comment: "ошибок никаких " ......... "error_reporting(E_ALL) - я не знаю что это" ........... мммм. и чего это нет ошибок? удивительно))

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.error-reporting.php  и  https://www.php.net/manual/ru/errorfunc.configuration.php